# How do I move all directories into a single directory efficiently in the same folder?

Tags: files, directory

I have 100 files in a single folder including a folder called "target." I want to migrate all the files in this folder into the folder target (except for the target folder itself).

Is there an efficient terminal command to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there are only the files (and the directory target) in your directory, simply use `mv`, rather than `find`:

```
mv * target
```

It will complain that 'target' can't be moved on itself, but the files will all be in target afterwards.

Comment: +1. However, I would use `target/` to make sure that I didn't accidentally rename all files to 'target'.

Comment: As long as you've got more than one file to move, that shouldn't be a problem.  It doesn't hurt though.

Comment: This does not handle hidden files.

Comment: Be aware that using this approach in scripts could give this error as fatal and abort the script!

Answer (score 2):

This works as well:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name target ! -name . -exec mv "{}" target \;
```

One of the key advantages of `find` over relying on bash completion is you get the hidden files at the same time. `mv * ...` won't do that.

You could perhaps go with something like:

```
mv -t target * .[^.]*
```

Or as James points out you could trim down the find command to only look at files... And as LoremIpsum pointed out if there are billions of them, using `xargs` would be slightly more efficient:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t target
```

Comment: You could probably simplify this to `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ...` to select by type rather than excluding particular names.

Comment: Maybe *xargs* could be used, too ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$ mv target ..
$ mv * ../target
$ mv ../target .
```

Comment: This is clean and better to use in scripts.

Comment: Only if you are allowed to create something in ..

Answer (score 0):

The approach of moving the destination directory to a previous one then moving everything to it and finally moving it back to current directory if fine. The only problem is that it does not work for a git project directory where we need to keep the history.

So for a git directory just move like this: **git mv * target -k**

The **-k** option is used to skip move/rename errors